# Give an example to show the eigenvalues can be changed when a multiply of one row is subtracted from one another

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following a good example?

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

then, multiply the first row with 1 and subtract the first row from the second row, we can get:

$$P'=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues P= 0,2
Eigenvalues P'=0,1

I wonder whether this can be a good example for the problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: Is there any general condition which needs to be satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows *precisely* what you've been asked to show, and isn't a particularly problematic example as far as calculation goes, either. Well done!